# INSERT rows from MAPPING table if not exist

Tags: sql-server

I have these 2 tables:

```
Table P

A  | B    
---------
X  | 2  
X  | 7  
X  | 10 
X  | 28
Y  | 24

Mapping M

C   | D
-----------
7   | 2136
28  | 786
24  | 4212
124 | 5311
935 | 6012
```

If I can find a matching value of column B in Table P with the value in column C of the Mapping M, I need to add the value of column D into Table P as well.

For example, the 1st record of X and 2 of Table P, I can't find 2 in column C of Mapping M, so nothing will be added.

2nd record X and 7, I can find 7 in column C, so I am gonna add X and 2136 into Table P.

Hence to be added into Table P:

```
X  | 2136
X  | 786
Y  | 4212
```

I find it challenging to INSERT these 3 rows.

I can do this:

```
SELECT P.*, M.D FROM @TableP P
    JOIN @MappingTable M ON (P.B = M.C)
```

and put the result into a TEMP table and INSERT, but how do I do it in 1 INSERT statement?

Comment: Start putting some effort

Comment: I am working out the answer at the same time too, so I will paste the answer if i have found it.

Comment: Add whatever you have tried so far

Comment: @VR46, I have added what I have got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized it's quite straightforward:

```
INSERT INTO @TableP
SELECT P.A, M.D FROM @TableP P
    JOIN @MappingTable M ON (P.B = M.C)
```